# Is there a way to add created_by and modified_by similar to how created and modified works in cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm wondering if there's a way to add `created_by` and `modified_by` similar to how `created` and `modified` work in CakePHP?

I like the fact that cake recognizes those fields and takes care of them automatically, regardless of the model, without me having to implement them at all.  I would like to add a similar feature using the current user id (in my application, there is always a userid, even if it sometimes may be 0).

I assume the starting place is `before_save()` in app_model?

--

Also, is there any way for me to get cake to recognize this as a foreign key to the user table automatically (similar to how it recognizes `user_id`), or will I have to add the has/belongs to relationship manually?  I ask because this will go on most of my models, so I'd prefer to reduce redundant code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first part of your question, I use this Behavior code to do exactly what you are looking for:

```
class UserLinkBehavior extends ModelBehavior
{
    /**
     * The string to use to retrieve the user id from CakeSession
     *
     * @var string
     */
    var $user_id_key = 'Auth.User.id';

    function setup(&$model, $settings)
    {
        if(isset($settings['user_id_key']))
        {
            $this->user_id_key = $settings['user_id_key'];
        }
    }

    function beforeSave(&$model)
    {
        App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');

        $logged_user_id = CakeSession::read($this->user_id_key);

        if(isset($logged_user_id))
        {
            $this->set_user_on_current_model($model, $logged_user_id);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set the created_by and modified_by user id on the current model
     *
     * @param Model $model
     * @param int $logged_user_id
     * @return void
     */
    private function set_user_on_current_model(&$model, $logged_user_id)
    {
        if(isset($logged_user_id))
        {
            /*
             * Id is not set -> it is a creation
             */
            if($model->hasField('created_by') && (!isset($model->data[$model->alias]['id']) || empty($model->data[$model->alias]['id'])))
            {
                if(!isset($model->data[$model->alias]['created_by']))
                {
                    $model->data[$model->alias]['created_by'] = $logged_user_id;

                    /*
                     * If the save is called with a whitelist, add 'created_by' to the whitelist
                     * in order to have this field saved as well
                     */
                    if(!empty($model->whitelist) && !in_array('created_by', $model->whitelist))
                    {
                        $model->whitelist[] = 'created_by';
                    }
                }
            }

            /*
             * Id is set -> it is an update
             */
            if($model->hasField('modified_by') && isset($model->data[$model->alias]['id']) && !empty($model->data[$model->alias]['id']))
            {
                $model->data[$model->alias]['modified_by'] = $logged_user_id;

                /*
                 * If the save is called with a whitelist, add 'modified_by' to the whitelist
                 * in order to have this field saved as well
                 */
                if(!empty($model->whitelist) && !in_array('modified_by', $model->whitelist))
                {
                    $model->whitelist[] = 'modified_by';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just declare it in your Model or your AppModel

```
var $actsAs = array('UserLink');
```

For the second part of your question, you could probably add a beforeFind() callback to the behavior and use the [model->bindModel()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly) function to link the model having the `created_by` and `modified_by` fields with a User model. Personaly I prefere to declare these links in each model manually when I need them.

Comment: there is also this: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/danfreak/2009/03/01/whodidit-behavior-automagic-created_by-and-modified_by-fields

Comment: Works like a charm... I'd still like to figure out the second half of the question there, but the behavior is perfect for modified and created by fields.  Thanks!

Comment: This is simply perfect.

Comment: Had to make few changes to the behavior to match signature to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be like the created and modified field but you can add this fields in the controller method wherever you want.

eg. in the add method you can add like follows.

```
 $this->request->data['ModelName']['created_by'] = $this->Auth->user['userid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this one](http://codingsips.alampk.com/cakephp-automatic-created-by-modified-by/) and working good for me its easy to implement and understand

```
<?php

App::uses('Model', 'Model');

class AppModel extends Model {
//get current logged-in user
    public function getCurrentUser() {
    App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
    $Session = new CakeSession();
    $user = $Session->read('Auth.User');
    return $user['id'];
  }

//populate created_by and modified_by
    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    parent::beforeSave($options);
    //find all fields from table created_by/modified_by exists
    $fields = array_keys($this->getColumnTypes());

    //get modal name to feed in data in appropriate array key        
    $modal = array_keys($this->data);
    $modal = $modal[0];

    //add created_by value
    if(in_array('created_by', $fields) && !isset($this->data[$modal]['id'])){
        //correct this line
        $this->data[$modal]['created_by'] = $this->getCurrentUser()==null?-1:$this->getCurrentUser();
        return true;
    }elseif(in_array('modified_by', $fields)){
        $this->data[$modal]['modified_by'] = $this->getCurrentUser()==null?-1:$this->getCurrentUser();
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```